# cannot load modules/mod_perl.so

Tags: apache, perl

Hola amigos vengo de nuevo con otro problema no puedo ejecutar xampp por que al iniciar xampp_start me sale un error que no he podido solucionar intente cambiar los archivos de otra estancia de xampp que creo que ese puede ser el problema.
estaría muy agradecido me pudiesen orientar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error dice que en el archivo de configuración del httpd se indica que se debe cargar mod_perl.so (el intérprete de Perl para Apache), pero que no lo encuentra.

Hay dos opciones: instalarlo o indicar en el archivo de configuración dónde está ese archivo; o quizás no lo necesites en absoluto: si la forma de trabajo de Perl con Apache es por medio del protocolo CGI, entonces no necesitas mod_perl para nada, así que puedes desactivarlo del archivo de configuración del Apache.

Comment: Gracias, creo si ocupar lo ya que estoy intentando instalar Ocs Invetory server y es por eso que me puse a ver y cambiar archivos de perl creo que ese fue mi principal error de cambiar archivos de la carpeta perl otra cosa par instalarlo y configurarlo? el mod_perl